# how to see which user has assigned a content_profile content type?

Tags: views

I´m using the module
http://drupal.org/project/content_profile
for drupal 6

I want to make a view where I show all the users and a link to their content profile, 
or even display some views from their profile..

Can´t seem to be able to do that, I don´t know where to pick the relation between the users and the content type

Currently my view is of the Usuer type..not Node..
I can handle PHP with customfield if I have to..don´t know where to start

Answer (score 1):

According to the code of the content profile module (I didn't test this) you can use views relations between profile nodes (ordinary cck node types) and users.

I'm not sure whether you have to base your view on the cck node type for the profile or users. But with one of these you should get an option to add the other side as a relation and then use fields of the user and the profile in the same view.

Answer (score -1):

In your view, in fields add User: Name

Tick "Output this field as a link" and set `users/[name]` in the "Link path" field